# HttpClient dependency Warning Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
    compile('org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2')
    compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpcore'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'commons-codec'
        }
}
```

I am receiving below warnings

```
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

No idea how to deal with it, any help would appreciate

Comment: remove `exclude module: 'httpclient'`

Comment: Nice try but No Luck @MD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

```
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
compile('org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2')
compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2') {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpcore'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

You've added `oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2` twice: once without any excludes and once with. Try removing the one without to see if your warnings go away (they should).

Also, with the latest build tools version (you may have to upgrade to `23.0.2`) you can remove this line:

```
compile('org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2')
```

(side note: that probably should've been a `provided`, not `compile`).

And then add to the `android` section, as [illustrated here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client):

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line, it is double

```
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2'
```